# JQuery Mobile Tabs Displaying Transparent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am in the process of making a web app that utilizes JQuery Mobile.

I have created a tab bar at the bottom of the screen, however, it is displaying with a purple link (the color should be white, as that is the default) and there is no background color behind the tabs.

Photos of the Visual Problem:

[image: transparentNav1]
[image: transparentNav2]

Code for Tab Bar:

```
<footer data-role="footer" data-id="navFooter" data-position="fixed">
<nav data-role="navbar" class="nav-footer">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#landmarks" id="LandmarksTab" data-icon="custom">Landmarks</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#map" id="MapTab" data-icon="custom">Map</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#more" id="MoreTab" data-icon="custom">More</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I know about the `enhanceWithin();` function, however, this function does not seem to help in this case.

Any ideas?

Comment: Add `data-theme` to footer or navbar. Another note, using `enhanceWithin()` to enhance footer isn't correct although it works. Use `.toolbar()`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. That solved the style problem, however, now it is not showing that it is selected, even when class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist" is added. Any ideas?

Comment: Classes added to anchor or list item?

Comment: Here is the class from the list item: class="ui-li-has-thumb ui-first-child"

Comment: Ui-btn-active should be added to anchor `a`.

Comment: Here is what I have under the a tag's class: class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist"